# Bitmapped blackboard-bold

Tags: fonts, blackboard

I've got a problem with the quality of the number, as can be seen, it's like it's got a pixel or something like that. How can I fix it?

[image]

There has to be a workaround for this issue. In TeX everything is possible.
mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathbbm{1} \]
\end{document}
```

This could be a workaround but it's not the same. Here I am using the cmathhbb package:

[image]

Comment: The code you posted doesn't give rise to the accompanying screenshot. Please clarify.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you are using the `bbm` package. Sadly, those fonts exist indeed only as bitmap fonts.

Comment: @campa Thank you. What a shame that it cannot be fixed :(

Comment: @Mico I just updated it. Done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re using a package only available in METAFONT.  There are many alternatives that come in outline fonts, such as `unicode-math` in LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.  In PDFTeX, you can use any of the fonts in `mathalpha` that support `\mathbb{1}`, or `cmathbb` (which as of November 2020 is too new for `mathalpha` to support, but is excellent).

Here is a MWE that works with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup} % Loads New Computer Modern Book.

\begin{document}
\[1 \in \mathbb{1} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: New Computer Modern Math Book sample]

Here is a version that uses New Computer Modern Math only for the blackboard-bold numerals:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{NewCMMath-Book}[
   range={\Bbbzero-\Bbbnine},
  Scale=MatchUppercase]

\begin{document}
\[1 \in \Bbbone \]
\end{document}
```

I would recommend you use Unicode in LuaLaTeX when you can, and legacy 8-bit fonts in PDFTeX when you have to.

In the comment, you say that you want only this one symbol from another font package.  Unlike `unicode-math`, there’s no standard way to do this with legacy fonts, but you might be able to find the correct font map in the package documentation or copy-and-paste the relevant lines from the `.sty` file.

Here, for example, is how you can get just that one symbol from `cmathbb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\CMath{U}{cmath}{m}{n}
\newcommand\Bbbone{\CMath{1}}

\begin{document}
\[1 \in \Bbbone \]
\end{document}
```

[image: cmathbb font sample]

Comment: Could you share a mwe? I only need to define a command for number 1. Using the package you're making mention of, meaning, cmathbb

Comment: If I use mathalpha or cmathbb it will affect all the equations. How can I define a command for printing the number 1, only ?

Comment: @NaveganTeX Okay, added.